# How to assign a link to omniauth facebook button

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

This is the code I have:

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
  <%- if devise_mapping.omniauthable? %>
    <%- resource_class.omniauth_providers.each do |provider| %>
      <%= link_to "Sign in", omniauth_authorize_path(resource_name, provider) %>
    <% end -%>
  <% end -%>
</div>
```

From the code above how can I change `link_to "Sign in"` with:

```
<button class="btn btn-facebook btn btn-lg btn-block"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x"></i> | Connect with <br> Facebook</button>
```

So instead of "sign in" simple button, I will show my custom made Facebook button.

Comment: Why don't you just style the anchor to look like the button?

Comment: i tried,but my method is wrong,i don't know how to do it.Please see updated question.

Comment: You can use [button_to](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/button_to).

Comment: i solved it,thanks for your effort!)

Comment: I'm a little late to the party, but if you're using Bootstrap, you can use the lovely social buttons available https://lipis.github.io/bootstrap-social/

Answer (score 0):

**Answer:** this is how i solved it

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
  <%- if devise_mapping.omniauthable? %>
    <%- resource_class.omniauth_providers.each do |provider| %>
      <%= link_to omniauth_authorize_path(resource_name, provider), class: 'btn btn-facebook btn btn-lg btn-block' do %>
        <i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x"></i>
        |Connect with <br> Facebook
      <% end %>
    <% end -%>
  <% end -%>
</div>
```

and it looks like this

[image: facebook button]

when someone clicks on that,it gets redirected to the required path,which is `omniauth_authorize_path(resource_name, provider)`

for those who need the css code for this button here it is

```
.btn-facebook.btn.btn-lg.btn-block {
  color: white;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  font-size: 1em;
  &:hover {
    color: white;
    background-color: RoyalBlue;
  }
}
```

I would appreciate if someone,would tell me how to make the "f" icon,to be in the center of the button.

*Thank you*

Answer (score 0):

What I did:

```
<%= link_to raw('<span class="fa fa-facebook"></span> Ingresa con Facebook'), user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook), :class => 'btn btn-block btn-social btn-facebook form-control' %>
```

Im using the bootstrap-social gem and the font-awesome gem to style it exactly like facebook looks :P

https://github.com/gavinkflam/bootstrap-social-rails